# How to kill a CLOSE_WAIT connection where the PID is not found?

Tags: sockets, port

I made a Flask app which links to a `while true` loop, and I killed the terminal with the trash icon in VSCode. Now I try to visit 3039 port, but it keeps on loading (I'm on Windows 11).

[image]

So, I tried `netstat - ano | findstr ":3039"` and I got `CLOSE_WAIT` connections with `2032` PID:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:54506        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:54507        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:59333        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:59334        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:59767        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:59768        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:59782        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60694        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60695        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60788        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60809        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60905        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60912        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:60995        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61138        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61226        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61410        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61411        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61640        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61641        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61643        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61647        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61660        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61754        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
  TCP    127.0.0.1:3039         127.0.0.1:61786        CLOSE_WAIT      2032
```

Now to kill, I used `taskkill /PID 2032 /F` but it says:

> ERROR: The process "2032" not found.

Also, I tried `stop-process 2032` and the response is:

```
stop-process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 2032.
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with flask

Comment: This is simply how sockets work. Even though the process that created the socket endpoints is already gone (which also means the `LISTENING` socket is also gone, since it was in the same process), the closed endpoints are still in the OS' tables for an extra period of time to help the OS flush any pending data left on the network for them. The OS will remove the entries after a few minutes.